# How can I build Aura Wm from Chrome OS in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, window-manager, chromeos

I saw the [OMG! Ubuntu article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/11/how-to-run-chromeos-in-ubuntu) on installing ChromeOS on top of Ubuntu. I liked the window manager, Aura, and want to add it along with Unity without the ChromeOS version active (to get Ubuntu applications and HDD data).

Is there an Ubuntu version of this WM to use in native Ubuntu?

If not, how do I get source code to compile it in Ubuntu? (I know this would be extremely unstable, most probably won't work, but why not try?)

I use 12.04 64bit, got 8GB RAM.

### What I want :-

Aura login :
[image: Login]

---

Actual look :

[image: Aura WM]

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

Found this project on GitHub which claims to do exactly what is required in the question.

From the README

```
lightdm-login-chromiumos

Installs Chromium OS Aura window manager to Ubuntu(64bit only), with embedded   
Chromium browser(canary snapshot). Binaries are downloaded from 
http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html
```

[Project Home Page](https://github.com/dz0ny/lightdm-login-chromeos)

---

Since `aura` has just been released, I don't think there is a separate package available.

But, since `aura` is part of the Chromium project which is open source, you can always download the source code.

You can checkout the source code using

```
svn checkout http://chromium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ chromium-read-only
```

The code for aura lies in `src/ui/aura` folder.

You can find the build instructions at http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/Aura

[Aura Design Document](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/aura-desktop-window-manager)

[image]

Comment: The problem here is that the instructions are for building this, *when* building the whole OS, there are no instructions for other distributions.

Comment: @UriHerrera Please Check the update to the answer.

Comment: It installs Chromium OS on top of Ubuntu (as a custom session as is detailed in the OMG! Ubuntu article), it does not Install Aura on its own.

Comment: @Karthik Saw that page (from the update). I have already installed it as a OS-on-OS. It does not provide HDD access. Thats why I asked this question. To get Aura *without* the rest of the useless clutter.

Comment: @Karthik How to download the code? `snv` seems to be stuck.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: The Chromium Wiki instructions, explain how to build Aura *within* ChromeOS or as part of ChromeOS image, *it does not explain how to install in Desktop Linux distros*, aka it doesn't provide ways of building by `make` `configure` `make install`. So your answers is half correct, that *is* the code, but it can't be built in Ubuntu.