# Different display and window managers for Ubuntu and how to install them

Tags: 12.04, display-manager

On surfing articles on Ubuntu, I came across posts for installing different desktop environments in Ubuntu. That got me thinking about different display & window managers they use and I made a list of a few window managers :

- Awesome
- Enlightment
- Fluxbox
- IceWM
- Xfwm (Xfce)
- OpenBox
- Sawfish
- ChromeOS (Aura WM rip)
- FVWM
- KDM (KDE)

I would like to install **ALL** of these in Ubuntu 12.04. How to do that. Got ChromeOS, need rest.

## Extra :

I took a look at [Joli OS](http://www.jolicloud.com/jolios) and loved their display. Only I don't know its name or if it is available for Ubuntu (though Joli OS is Ubuntu derivative). Can any one give me that desktop environment or instructions on how to install it?

## Update

Got almost all but I need Joli OS's display manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the packages that provide you the listed Window Managers.

- awesome
- *e17 - Is both a Window Manager and a Desktop Environment.*
- fluxbox
- icewm
- xfwm4
- openbox
- sawfish
- fvwm
- kwin
- mutter
- metacity
- compiz
- blackbox

You can install these packages through `synaptic` or by typing

```
sudo apt-get install <pkg-name>
<pkg-name> --replace
```

in the terminal.

---

Apart from the ones you have listed these are some Display Managers

- gdm - Gnome Display Manager
- ldm - LSTP Display Manager
- xdm - X Display Manager
- sdm - Secure Display Manager
- wdm - WINGs Display Manager
- kdm - KDE Display Manager
- slim - Simple login manager
- lightdm - Ubuntu's defualt DM

---

For the various available Desktop Environments please [refer here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available)

Comment: Will this affect system stability? Also, can I do this with desktop environments?

Comment: I wont say it will affect system stability. Although I don't think the Display Manager of one Desktop Environment will fit properly into another Desktop Environment. I have not tried but please feel free to try and post the results.

Comment: Using Different Desktop Environments on the other hand is much more stable. You can install a variety of Desktop Environments and just choose which one to use at login. But, apps designed for one Desktop Environment may not have a good look and feel in another Desktop Environment.

Comment: I would also like a list of all desktop environments. Can you add it in your answer?

Comment: You can refer http://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available for the various available Desktop Environments.

Comment: Nice. Since you are acting like a jinnie, can you take a look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223956/can-i-get-a-version-of-aura-wm-for-ubuntu-12-04) and give me a fork of Aura WM which runs on native Ubuntu?

Comment: If the post answers your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6680/discussion-between-vedvals-and-karthik)